# Use printf to format output directed to a .txt file

Tags: bash, printf

I have the following code which inserts 94 x's into a .txt file:

```
printf 'x%.0s' {1..94}
```

Is it possible to combine a new line being inserted before the 94 x's are output?

I have tried:

```
printf '\n x%.0s' {1..94}
printf "\n x%.0s" {1..94}
```

but I cannot get it to work.

I could use `echo -e "\n"` in the line of code above, however this is a recurring line of code and I'd prefer to combine it into one if possible

Comment: Not like that, but you could print 94 spaces and convert those to x's: `printf '\n%94s' '' | tr \  x`

Comment: Or store the formatted string into a variable: `separator=$(echo; printf 'x%.0s' {1..94})` and then expand that where you repeatedly need it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can achieve this in a single `printf` (works with `bash`):

```
printf '%.1s' $'\n' x{1..94}
```

**Code:**:

```bash
printf '%.1s' $'\n' x{1..10}

xxxxxxxxxx
```

PS: Note that here I've used `10` for this example to be able to show the working approach with generated output.

**Explanation:**

- `$'\n'`: Will emit a line break character
- `x{1..10}` will generate this output:

```bash
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
```

and `printf` format `%.1s` will print first letter i.e. `\n` or `x` from the input arguments to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple and obvious solution is to do one, then the other.

```
printf 'x%.0s' {1..94} >file
printf '\n' >>file
```

Printing a newline *before* the text is odd, but if you really genuinely need that, just swap the statements. Note that the first creates a file with `>`, the second appends with `>>`; obviously, don't swap the redirections around.

If you want to avoid repetitions, put it in a function.

```
ninetyfourx () {
    printf 'x%.0s' {1..94}
    printf '\n'
}

ninetyfourx >file
ninetyfourx >another
```